# Android let Toast come before Thread.sleep // Systemclock.sleep

Tags: android, sleep

I want to make a Toast appear and THEN let a sleep operate.

If i do that, the Toast appears AFTER the sleep, but i want it the other way around. Anyone has a suggestion? Here my code for this

```
switch (checkedRadioButton) {
                  case R.id.radio0 : radioButtonSelected = "radiobutton1";
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  vd.vibrate(100);        
                  android.os.SystemClock.sleep(1000);         
                  vd.vibrate(100);
```

thanks so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The display of toast is an asynchronous (i.e not a blocking call) operation, means once the toast request is executed, the operating system jumps to the next operation and meanwhile the toast is prepared and displayed.

To acquire your default behavior, you should execute the thread-sleep call after few seconds of delay. Use a `Handler` and its **postDelay** method for this.

Delay time should be like:

```
LONG_DELAY = 3500;  // 3.5 seconds
SHORT_DELAY = 2000; // 2 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just discovered that Handler stuff but your answer made all that more clear for me. I will upvote this answer as soon as i have 15 points

Answer (score 0):

Try to use AsyncTask class.Write this code as it is. no need to take the name of variable of class AsyncTask.

```
   new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
               Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(context, "Task completed",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
               toast2.show();

           }

           @Override
           protected void onPreExecute() {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "here is your text before Sleep", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }

           @Override
           protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

                   try {

                       Thread.sleep(1000); // time in milisec 1000ms= 1sec

                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }


               return null;
           }

       }.execute();
```